# Expected value and variance of a random point in a triangle

Tags: triangles, expected-value, variance

I've done some reading and googling for my problem below but I am still unable to solve this problem as the part where X is a continuous random variable is plaguing me.

A point S is randomly placed in triangle ABC. Let X be the be the continuous random variable representing the distance from S to AB. Find $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathsf E[X]$ scales linearly with $X$, and $\mathsf{Var}(X)$ scales quadratically with $X$, so we can scale the triangle such that the height above $AB$ is $1$ and then rescale accordingly.

The probability of choosing a point at height $X$ above $AB$ is $0$ at $C$ and increases linearly towards $AB$. Thus its expected value is

$$
\mathsf E[X]=\frac{\int_0^1x(1-x)\mathrm dx}{\int_0^1(1-x)\mathrm dx}=\frac{\frac12-\frac13}{\frac12}=\frac13
$$

and the expected value of its square is

$$
\mathsf E\left[X^2\right]=\frac{\int_0^1x^2(1-x)\mathrm dx}{\int_0^1(1-x)\mathrm dx}=\frac{\frac13-\frac14}{\frac12}=\frac16\;,
$$

so that the variance is

$$
\mathsf{Var}[X]=\mathsf E\left[X^2\right]-\mathsf E[X]^2=\frac16-\left(\frac13\right)^2=\frac1{18}\;.
$$

Accordingly, for a triangle with height $h$ above $AB$, the expected distance from $AB$ is $\frac h3$, and the variance of the distance from $AB$ is $\frac{h^2}{18}$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have some questions. Can you elaborate more on the first sentence and how did you get the formula for $E(X)$?

Comment: @Moonshine45: In both expressions for the expected values the numerator is the integral over the unnormalized probability density ($1-x$) times the quantity being averaged ($x$ or $x^2$), and the denominator provides the normalization. About the first sentence, it would be good to know which part you don't understand. Are you familiar with scaling in the context of random variables? Or in the context of geometry? Or netiher?

Comment: I am familiar with random variables but have not come across them in the context of scaling and geometry.

Comment: @Moonshine45: $X$ appears linearly in the definition of $\mathsf E[X]$, so if we scale $X$ by a factor $s$, then $\mathsf E[X]$ is also scaled by a factors $s$. By contrast, $X$ appears quadratically in the definition of $\mathsf{Var}[X]$, so if we scale $X$ by a factor $s$, then $\mathsf{Var}[X]$ is scaled by $s^2$. I used this in the last paragraph to get the actual expectation and variance for arbitrary height $h$, based on the case where $h=1$ (as $X$ scales with $h$).